# How can I built a HOC for guarding routes if I am using httpOnly cookie?

Tags: next.js

I am storing my token in a httpOnly cookie, but when I want to built a HOC for guarding the routes there is no way to access the cookie directly inside a component, I have to do it inside the server side,
I tried to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
import Cookie from "cookies";
const withAuth = (Page) => {
  Page.getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
    const cookie = new Cookie(req, res);
    const token = cookie.get("token");
    if (!token)
      return {
        redirect: {
          permanent: false,
          destination: "/login",
        },
      };
    return {
      props: {
        token,
      },
    };
  };
  return Page;
};

export default withAuth;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getServerSideProps` function only works in **pages, not components.**

The following snippet should help you create a HOC for authentication. This example uses the concepts of closures. I'll call this one `withAdministrator.jsx`.

```js
// withAdministrator.jsx
export default (GetServerSidePropsFunction) => async (ctx) => {
  // 1. Check if there is a token.
  const token = ctx.req.cookies?.jwt || null;

  // 2. Perform an authorized HTTP GET request to the private API to get user data.
  // In here, assume that 'getAuth' is a function to perform authorized GET request using the token value in the 'Authorization' header.
  const { data } = await getAuth(`${process.env.PRIVATE_API_URL}/api/v1/users/user`, token);

  // 3. If there is no user, or the user is not an admin, then redirect to unauthorized.
  if (!data || data.role !== 'admin') {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/unauthorized',
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  // 4. Return via closure: 'GetServerSidePropsFunction'.
  return await GetServerSidePropsFunction(ctx);
};
```

You'll call it like this. Let's say you want to access the `/admin` route.

```js
export const getServerSideProps = withAdministrator(() => {
  return {
    props: {},
  };
});

const Admin = () => {
  return (
    <YourComponent />
  );
};
```

You can do anything you want inside the returned function. For example, you might want to fetch data after authenticating the user.

Further reading: [Data fetching in Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching).